# tomcat 7.0.23 cannot establish SSL connection from apache server. 

Tags: tomcat, ssl, proxy, cluster-computing

Hi i have the following server.xml settings.

```
Server port="7005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN-TOMCAT-C">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="7070" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
                   connectionTimeout="20000" 
                   redirectPort="7443" />
        <Connector port="7443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" 
                   SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" 
                   keystoreFile="${key.path}\compresskey.bin" keystorePass="${keystorePass}" 
                   compression="on" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
        <Connector port="7009" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol" redirectPort="7443" enableLookups="false"  />

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat-c">
            <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                     channelSendOptions="10">
                <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.BackupManager"
                       expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                       notifyListenersOnReplication="true"
                       mapSendOptions="10"/>
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                         filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.css;.*\.txt;"/>
                <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
            </Cluster>

<Context path="/mvc2_app1"
                      docBase="${user.home}\webapps\mvc2_app1"
                      cookies="true"
                      override="true"
                      reloadable="false"
                      swallowOutput="true"
                      distributable="true"
                      logEffectiveWebXml="true"
                      xmlNamespaceAware="false"
                      xmlValidation="false"
                      className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext">
</context>
</service>

</host>
```

my worker.properties

```
worker.tomcat-c.port=7009
worker.tomcat-c.host=localhost
worker.tomcat-c.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat-c.lbfactor=1
```

Here is my httpd.conf setting.

```
<VirtualHost ${host}:443> 
SSLEngine On ServerName ${host} 
ErrorLog "logs/error.log" 
LogLevel warn 
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/server.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/server.key 
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown 
SSLProxyEngine On 
ServerAdmin local@admin.com 
RewriteEngine On 

ProxyPreserveHost On #applications on 5443 
ProxyPass /mvc2_app1 https://${host}:7443/mvc2_app1 

ProxyPassReverse /mvc2_app1 https://${host}:7443/mvc2_app1 
</virtual_host>
```

When i try connecting to https://localhost/mvc2_app1, i get an error 500 proxy error.

Here is my error.log
    proxy: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /mvc2_app1
    proxy: pass request body failed to ${local ip}:7443 (${host}) from ${local ip}

any advice or tips?

Thanks.

-- update -- 
I can connect to apache server without problem. https://localhost works but https://localhost/mvc2_app1 does not.

So my tomcat log is this.

```
Dec 25, 2011 10:21:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7070"]
Dec 25, 2011 10:21:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 25, 2011 10:21:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7443"]
Dec 25, 2011 10:21:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 25, 2011 10:21:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-7009"]
    Dec 25, 2011 10:21:58 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl setupSocket
    INFO: Setting cluster mcast soTimeout to 500
    Dec 25, 2011 10:21:58 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
    INFO: Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:4
    Dec 25, 2011 10:21:59 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
    INFO: Done sleeping, membership established, start level:4
    Dec 25, 2011 10:21:59 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
    INFO: Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:8
    Dec 25, 2011 10:22:00 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
    INFO: Done sleeping, membership established, start level:8
    Dec 25, 2011 10:22:00 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.tipis.AbstractReplicatedMap init
    INFO: Initializing AbstractReplicatedMap with context name:/mvc2_app1
    Dec 25, 2011 10:22:00 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.tipis.AbstractReplicatedMap init
    INFO: Initializing AbstractReplicatedMap with context name:/mvc2_app2
```

Comment: The error i get is [error] proxy: pass request body failed to ${ip_addrsss}:${tomcat_port} (${host}) from ....

Comment: That's not a programming question, btw: not for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i updated to tomcat 7.0.25 and my application runs. I at least got to see configuration error in my spring 3 application and was able to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up `mod_jk` and `mod_proxy`.

The `worker.properties` parameters are for `mod_jk`, which uses AJP, but they're not used by `mod_proxy_ajp` (which is nowadays recommended over `mod_jk` for AJP connections).

Your `ProxyPassReverse` configuration uses `mod_proxy_http` (an `https://` URL, not `ajp://`), not `mod_jk` or `mod_proxy_ajp`. There isn't much point enabling AJP at all on Tomcat for this.

You probably don't need to use HTTPS between your Apache Httpd server and your Apache Tomcat server (from localhost to localhost). However, if you feel you need to, use the `SSLProxy*` directives, as mentioned at the top of the [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) documentation.

Comment: thanks Bruno. I think my problem has to do with tomcat and not Apache.
I try hitting https://${host}:7443/mvc2_app1 and it just loads and loads and time out. I change the configuration so that original tomcat instance would load for me https://${host}:7443/still no response at all.

Comment: Also in addition I have the open port when i start it.    
  `TCP    [::]:7009              [::]:0                 LISTENING`
  `TCP    [::]:7070              [::]:0                 LISTENING`
  `TCP    [::]:7443              [::]:0                 LISTENING`
I think my problem is this: 
SEVERE: No global naming context defined for server